# Ubuntu Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: ubuntu, synaptic-pkg-mgr

could someone help me to find a solution for this problem,

when i start running synaptic package manager it gives me the following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct
 the problem. 
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is tested on terminal as well. it gives following output:

```
root@kapia-laptop:/home/kapia# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: status database area is locked by another process
```

Comment: Just reboot, all open dpkg processes will be closed... :) Then open synaptic again

Answer (score 1):

that means you have already an process of dpkg running, either as synaptic, update manager or apt-get/aptitude

as a last resort, if nothing works you can try deleting the lockfile `/var/cache/apt/lock`, but be careful, this can potentially corrupt your package database

Comment: or there could be a stale lockfile?

Comment: it's my experience this is the correct general case -- i've left aptitude running in another terminal and forgotten about it.  if `ps` doesn't show any other dpkg/synaptic/aptitude processes running on the system, assuming the lockfile to be stale may be reasonable -- but i'd try rebooting before manually removing the lockfile.  just in case.

Answer (score 0):

When you running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` be sure, you have closed synaptic package manager, autoupdate dialog and all other software related to packages. Only one instance at time can work with packages database.

Comment: No it shouldn't.  linux != server (at least not all the time).

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, I'd just reboot. Let Linux do it's thing and close the programs properly for you. Either reboot through the graphical interface, or open terminal and run `sudo reboot` or `sudo shutdown -r now`. Upon rebooting, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. If you are still getting errors regarding dpkg being locked, follow knittl's answer.